# Laravel 5.1 foreign keys in model factory

Tags: foreign-keys, laravel-5.1, seeding, faker

How do you define foreign keys in a model factory. For example if I have a organisations table which has a foreign key to the countries table, in my model factory I'm having to define a dummy value for the country id as follows:

```
$factory->define(App\Organisation::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
      'name' => $faker->company,
      'country_id' => 197,
   ];
});
```

In my organisations table seeder class I am doing the following but the faker object isn't present - do I need to create a new faker object in my seeder class?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class OrganisationsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

   public function run()
   {
      $countryIds = Country::lists('id')->all();

      factory('App\Organisation', 3)->create([
        // override factory default
        'country_id' => $faker->randomElement[$countryIds],
    ]);
   }
}
```

Database seeder class

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
     public function run()
     {

        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('CountriesTableSeeder');
        $this->call('OrganisationsTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
     }
}
```

Whats the best way to define the foreign keys when defining model factories? Is it possible to omit the country_id from the model factory and add it in the seeder class instead - from the documention it seems you can only override an existing value defined in the model factory but you cant add a new value via the seeder class - correct me if i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I may be a bit late on this one but I was having the same issue, this fixed it for me. You should be able to do

```
$factory->define(App\Organisation::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
      'name' => $faker->company,
      'country_id' => factory(App\Country::class)->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

and then in your seed you just need to call

```
factory(App\Organisation::class, 5)->create();
```

and it will create the countries for you as well.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that each `organization` will have one different country and it will never use an existing one, right?

Comment: mmmmh, it's been a while since I wrote this code, but your observation seems correct, although I didn't really care about using an existing country at the time I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that the Laravel team, Otwell, Stauffer et.al., suggest is like this.

Testing > [Adding Relations To Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#working-with-databases)

[Adding relationships to your models](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/better-integration-testing-in-laravel-5.1-model-factories#adding-relationships-to-your-models)

**ModelFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\Organisation::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
      'name' => $faker->company,
      'country_id' => 197,
   ];
});

$factory->define(App\Country::class, function ($faker) {
   return [
      'name' => $faker->country,
   ];
});
```

**seeder**

```
$organisations = factory('App\Organisation', 3)
  ->create()
  ->each(function($$organisation) {
      $organisation->relatedItems()->save(factory('App\Country')->make());
  });
```